# How to measure in pixels and compile with Xetex?

Tags: xetex, geometry, paper-size

For some reason, I have to use pixels as a unit of measurement, and compile with Xetex, which entails the following error I am trying to overcome:

```
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \Gm@process
Missing \begin{document}. \Gm@process
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \Gm@process
```

Here is a minimal code :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[papersize={500px,1000px}]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

And a big thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the  width and height of a pixel? ;-)

Comment: Pixels are not a valid measurement within TeX and for good reason. It is a type-setting engine designed for paper, not for screens. You can introduce pixels as a measurement with a suitable scaling to an existing unit such as pt. I would however strongly advise against that; If you want to draw pictures, use another program or just convert the .pdf to an image of appropriate size.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer On my system, one pixel is one `screenwidth/1920` :).

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner: On my system the pixel width changes from `screenwidth/1920` to `screenwidth/1024`, depending on my mood ;-)